# How to Execute multiple XML statements

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssas, olap-cube, multidimensional-cube

I have a Microsoft Multi-Dimensional OLAP cube that needs to have partitions created and processed. I know how to generate the scripts, but Im not sure how to execute each statement consecutively. Id really prefer not to execute every statement manually. So does XML have an equivalent of GO in T-SQL? Below I have two statements separated by the GO command. What should I replace GO with?

The statements are for processing dimensions, but I need to do the same with Partition Create statements.  Is running the create statements and then process statements all that is required for new functioning partitions? If these Partitions are empty and new, do I need to do a FULL process or will just a Data Process suffice?

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Parallel>
        <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
            <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RealMedRemit</DatabaseID>
                <CubeID>Remit</CubeID>
                <MeasureGroupID>FactRemit</MeasureGroupID>
                <PartitionID>Fact Remit - 2024-Q03</PartitionID>
            </Object>
            <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
            <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
        </Process>
    </Parallel>
</Batch>

GO

<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Parallel>
        <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
            <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RealMedRemit</DatabaseID>
                <CubeID>Remit</CubeID>
                <MeasureGroupID>FactRemit</MeasureGroupID>
                <PartitionID>Fact Remit - 2024-Q04</PartitionID>
            </Object>
            <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
            <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
        </Process>
    </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

Comment: Have you tried combining the two XML trees under a single Batch root element yet? e.g.: `<Batch ...><Parallel>...</Parallel><Parallel>...</Parallel></Batch>`

Comment: Yeah I have tried putting both statements in <Batch>...</Batch> and I keep getting the same error

Comment: I went back and played with it some and your suggestion worked. Thanks. The difference was using a a full Batch tag you get with a generated script ```<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com>```